# Running an external command in VBScript with user input

Tags: input, vbscript, cmd

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a popup that asks a user for a numeric value, when that value gets entered, it is then placed in a certain position in a command-line and then run.

I am using this for is for an accounting software. If you need to delete a transaction from a database, you find a job ID in a report, then you run a command and enter the job id at the end of a certain string and it wipes out the transactions in the DB.

I am just trying to simplify the method....any help?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading [this documentation](http://ss64.com/vb/inputbox.html) on InputBoxes in vbscript.

You can set a variable to equal the input box, eg. `strInput = InputBox("prompt")` then pass the variable `strInput` to the dos command.

You might also read about running a command from vbscript [here](http://ss64.com/vb/run.html).

So your code would be, roughly,

```
strInput = InputBox("prompt")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "program.exe /argument=" & strInput
```